# Is there a way to add a button to Windows 11's start menu's power options?

Tags: windows-11, desktop-customization

Is there a way to add a button to the Windows 11 start menu power options that would activate a script?

place where new button would go:

[image: place where new button would go]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not without a lot of effort. A .net developer could probably use the windows api code to adjust it, like the Win+X Menu Editor does. The only built-in options are the ability to show/hide the buttons for sleep and hibernate: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/sleep-option.png

Comment: If it is your goal to always execute a script upon shutdown, consider Group Policy logoff or shutdown scripts.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?